# Displaying distinct datetime column in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, datetime, drop-down-menu

In my C# application I am creating a dropdownlist that will display distinct datetime column of my sql database.

when I write the query:

```
Select distinct DateTimeColumn from tablename1
```

I get a list of distinct datetime in the format: 2013-03-31 09:04:00.955

but when I try to display the same detail in my dropdownlist using the code:

```
SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tablename1 order by DateTimeColumn desc", sqlconn);
            DataSet ds0 = new DataSet();
            cmd0.Fill(ds0);
            DataView source0 = new DataView(ds0.Tables[0]);
            DataTable dt0 = new DataTable();
            cmd0.Fill(dt0);
            Cache["data"] = ds0;

            DataSet dataset_new1 = new DataSet();
            dataset_new1 = (DataSet)Cache["data"];
            DataView dataview_new1 = dataset_new1.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            DataTable datatable_new1 = dataview_new1.ToTable(true, "DateTimeColumn");
            DropDownList1.DataSource = datatable_new1;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DateTimeColumn";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "DateTimeColumn";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

I get the format of my datetime as: 3/31/2013 09:04:00 AM

I have no idea why my format is getting changed! please help!! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DataTextFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextformatstring.aspx) property and use a [Custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

I didn't tested, but it should be something like this or similar

```
DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem! I wrote:   DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.fff}"; And it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening because you are running the query in another tool that formats text the way you expect. When you run it in your app, it uses the data locale by default (unless otherwise specified)

You will get the desired result if you change your `select` statement to:

```
select distinct DATE_FORMAT(DateTimeColumn,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f') 
from tablename1
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but my problem solved by the other method!